# How to configure client timeouts for http streamed responses?

Tags: http, timeout, client, jetty

I'm trying to perform a request to an http endpoint that streams data for a non-trivial amount of time with Jetty HttpClient. I want to setup a timeout to bound the request time budget. I'm expecting to give up after a precise amount of time in case I'm not receiving any data, but to let the request finish if it started to stream the response.

```
httpClient.newRequest("http://some-host.local/an/endpoint/that/streams)
            .method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .idleTimeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .timeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) 
            .send();
```

I understand that the request goes trough several states: Queued,Begin, [...], Completed.
I found these two timeouts:

- `timeout()` - Starts on the Queued state; it is disabled on Completed state.
- `idleTimeout()` - Starts after the Begin state; it is reset each time content arrives; it is disabled on Completed state

When many requests are Queued but not yet Begin (e.g. all connections are used), the `idleTimeout()` does not apply to them. A request can only be evicted from the queue by a `timeout` expiration.

The problem I am facing is that I'm having troubles to set a meaningful timeout that allows me to stop a request that takes too long to start, without also stopping requests that are receiving streamed data.

Is there a way to take into account the time spent awaiting in the queue? I'm trying to bound the time from `send()` to first byte received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a custom requirement.

Create a custom `Listener`, which implements both a selection of `RequestListener` and `ResponseListener` interfaces.

This custom `Listener` will be responsible for tracking requests that "take too long to start" and when the timer has triggered evaluate if the exchange is valid, or should be cancelled via `Request.abort()`.

Some key events:

- The `Request.BeginListener` should start your timing for the request (this means the request was created, but not yet queued).
- The `Request.QueuedListener` is when the request hits the queue, but has not yet been sent).
- The `Request.CommitListener` is when the request has been sent to the remote server.
- The `Response.BeginListener` the first line of the response header has been parsed.
- The `Response.ContentListener` the first byte of response content has been received.

For other events, check out the other `RequestListener` and `ResponseListener` classes and their javadoc.

`RequestListener` implementations are registered via

```java
httpClient.getRequestListeners().add(mycustomlistener);
```

`ResponseListener` implementations are registered via the `Request` object.

```java
client.newRequest(uri)
   .onResponseBegin(listener)
   .onResponseContent(listener)
   .onResponseSuccess(listener)
   .onResponseFailure(listener)
   .send(listener); // async send (good place to cancel timer on the exchange)
```

Comment: That's what I was anticipating, thanks :)